# fatal error: apr_time.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake

```
#include <apr_time.h>
```

Is causing the following compile error:

```
fatal error: apr_time.h: No such file or directory
```

When I do

```
locate apr_time.h
```

It outputs

```
/usr/include/apr-1.0/apr_time.h
```

So I believe I have correctly installed the library using `sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev`.  If I do

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs apr
```

I get

```
Package apr was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `apr.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'apr' found
```

How do I make sure that `apr_time.h` is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#include <apr-1.0/apr_time.h>
```

instead.

Comment: This solution only works if you own the source code that it's being included in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apr-1` instead of `apr`.

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs apr-1
```

If you want to build, do this.

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs apr-1` main.c -o main
```

## Note

In that case, you can look for a `.pc` included in the package.

```
dpkg -L libapr1-dev | grpe .pc

-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/apr-1.pc
```